# How find the smallest sphere touching $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$

Tags: geometry

$L_{1}$ is the line $\{(t+1,2t-4,-3t+5):t\in R\}$  and $L_{2}$ is the line $\{(4t-12,-t+8,t+17),t\in R\}$,

Find the smallest sphere touching $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$

This problem is 20th Putnam 1959 problem can see:http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/putn59.html

But I can't this problem solution.Thank you can someone have methods? Thank you

My try

$$L_{1}:x=t+1,y=2t-4,z=-3t+5$$
$$L_{2}:x=4t-12,y=-t+8,z=t+17$$

then I can't，Thank you very much

Comment: Find the pair of points on $L_1$ and $L_2$ which have the smallest distance between eachother. These are the touchpoints.

Comment: the key How find it? Thank you

Comment: You know how to calculate the distance between a point and a line?   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line Use this method to find the point on $L_1$ which has the shortest distance to line $L_2$. It is sufficient to determine the shortest squared distance and thus avoid square roots.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Solution 1.:**

The squared *Pythagorean* distance between two points on $L_1$ and $L_2$ is:

$$\begin{align}
d^2(t_1, t_2) & = (t_1+1 - 4t_2 + 12)^2 + (2t_1 - 4 + t_2 -8)^2 + (-3t_1 + 5 - t_2 -17)^2 \\
& = 14t_1^2 +2t_1t_2 + 50t_1 + 18t_2^2 -104t_2 + 457
\end{align}$$

To find the minimum for $t_1$, the derivative has to be zero:

$$\begin{align}
\delta d^2(t_1, t_2) \over \delta t_1 & = 2(14t_1 + t_2 + 25) = 0 \\
t_1 & = - \frac{t_2 + 25}{14}
\end{align}$$

The squared distance now is solely depending on $t_2$:

$$\begin{align}
d^2(t_2) & = (- \frac{t_2 + 25}{14} + 1 - 4t_2 + 12)^2 + (2 (- \frac{t_2 + 25}{14}) - 4 + t_2 -8)^2 + (-3(- \frac{t_2 + 25}{14}) + 5 - t_2 -17)^2 \\
& = \frac{251t_2^2 - 1506t_2 + 5773}{14}
\end{align}$$

Again, the derivative has to be zero:

$$\begin{align}
\delta d^2(t_2) \over \delta t_2 & = \frac {251(t_2 - 3)}{7} = 0 \\
t_2 & = 3
\end{align}$$

By inserting $t_2$ in the expression for $t_1$:

$$t_1 = -2$$

By inserting $t_1$ and $t_2$, we get as touchpoints of the sphere:

$$\begin{align}
P_1 & = \{ -1 ; -8; 11 \} \\
P_2 & = \{  0 ;  5; 20 \}
\end{align}$$

The center of the sphere is the middle between the touchpoints:

$$M = \{ -\frac{1}{2}; -\frac{3}{2}; \frac{31}{2} \}$$

The squared radius follows from the squared distance of the touchpoints:

$$\begin{align}
r^2 & = \frac{d^2}{4} \\
& = \frac{251*3^2 - 1506*3+5773}{14*4} \\
& = \frac{3514}{56} = \frac{251}{4}
\end{align}$$

This finally leads to the equation of the smallest sphere touching $L_1$ and $L_2$:

$$(x + \frac{1}{2})^2 + (y + \frac{3}{2})^2 + (z - \frac{31}{2})^2 =  \frac{251}{4}$$

or

$$(2x + 1)^2 + (2y + 3)^2 + (2z - 31)^2 =  251$$

---

**Alternative Solution 2.:**

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HC5YikQxwZA) nicely explains a different approach based on geometric reasoning:

The vector $\vec{P}$ between the two touchpoints $P_1$ and $P_2$ must be perpendicular to both direction vectors of the lines $L_1$ and $L_2$.

$$\begin{align}
\vec{P} = P_1 - P_2 & = \left[\array{(t_1+1)-(4t_2-12) \cr (2t_1-4)-(-t_2+8) \cr (-3t_1+5) - (t_2+17)}\right] \\
& = \left[\array{t_1-4t_2+13 \cr 2t_1+t_2-12 \cr -3t_1-t_2-12}\right] \\
\\
\vec{P}\left[\array{1 \cr 2 \cr -3}\right] & = 1(t_1-4t_2+13) + 2(2t_1+t_2-12) - 3(-3t_1-t_2-12) = 0 \\
& = 14t_1+t_2+25 \\
t_2 & = -14t_1 -25 \\
\\
\vec{P}\left[\array{4 \cr -1 \cr 1}\right] & = 4(t_1-4t_2+13) - 1(2t_1+t_2-12) + 1(-3t_1-t_2-12) = 0 \\
& = -t_1-18t_2+52 \\
\\
t_1 & = -18t_2 + 52 \\
& = -18(-14t_1-25) + 52 \\
& = 252t_1 + 502 \\
& = -\frac{502}{251} \\
& = -2 \\
t_2 & = -14*(-2)-25 \\
& = 3
\end{align}$$

Once the values for $t_1$ and $t_2$ are determined, the equation of the sphere is derived as shown above.